# Error in Android Studio - "cannot find symbol method findviewbyid(int)"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

There is an error in the webview part. Please help me out. Following the tutorial here I have set up an app that should be able to open a URL and place it into an WebView. The only issue is that it cannot find findViewById  code is here:

```
//webviewcode
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;

    import info.healthazure.materialdesign.R;


    public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {
        private WebView myWebView;
        public MessagesFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false);
            myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.medplusmart.com/");



            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
    }
```

Any help for solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using just this `findViewById()` use `rootView.findViewById()` as your entire layout is inflated inside rootview.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
myWebView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

instead of

```
myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
```